# Auto Launch not working for windows 10 kiosk

Tags: windows

Building a win 10 kiosk 1809 machine, LTSC. Used the WCD that came with the 1809 version of the ADK. Most of it is working, custom layout for the desktop, only one app is visible and it runs under the kiosk user account. However I have the app set to auto lauch on boot but that doesn't work. The event logs are clear, including all the applocker, assignedaccess logs. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the xml I'm importing into the WCD during build.


    
        
            
                
                 
                 
                 
                 
                 
                
            
            
        
          
          
            
              
            
              
            </start:Group>
              </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
            </StartLayoutCollection>
          </DefaultLayoutOverride>
        </LayoutModificationTemplate>
        ]]>